# File Upload won't trigger on the following loop except the first one

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using Twitter Modal Bootstrap for my Web Application. In one of the feature of the app is to display a table with corresponding information (I used mysql_query to populate the information). For each row of the table, there is a "View" button. Clicking that View Button will open a "Modal" pop-up which includes a form inside. As you can see, I'm trying to upload a file using AJAX. This is successfully done when I try to do it on the first row. But when I try to do it on the following row, I can't upload the file as if there's no form in it.

Table:

```
<table border = '1' width = "30%">
    <tr>
        <th>Asset Picture</th>
        <th>Asset Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assets") or die("No records found.".mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
    {
        echo "<tr>
                  <td><img src = '$row[asset_Picture]' width = '100%'></td>
                  <td>$row[asset_Name]></td>
                  <td><button data-toggle='modal' id = 'buttonView' style = '$row[asset_ID]' data-target='#myModalEdit-$row['asset_ID']' type='button' class='btn btn-link'>View</button></td>
              </tr>";
        echo "<div class='modal fade' id='myModalEdit-$row['asset_ID']' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>"; ?>
            <div class='modal-dialog'>
                <div class='modal-content'>
                    <div class='modal-header'>
                        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                        <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'><b>Testing</b></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-body'>
                    <?php
                    echo    "<form style = '$row[asset_ID]' id='uploadForm-$row[asset_ID]' action = 'upload.php' method = 'POST'>
                            <center><img value = '$row[asset_Picture]' id = asset_Picture-$row[asset_ID]' class = 'img-thumbnail' src = '$row[asset_Picture]' width = '60%'></center><br><br>
                            <b class = 'text-danger'>Change Asset Picture?</b><br><br>
                            <input class = 'form-controlModal' type = 'file' name = 'userImage' id = 'file-$row[asset_ID]' accept='image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/jpg, image/png' style = 'width:460px;'>
                            <input type='submit' id = 'uploadPicture' style = '$row[asset_ID]' class='btn btn-primary' value = 'Upload'>
                            </form>";
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <div align = 'left' class='modal-footer'>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#uploadPicture').click( function(e) {
    var edit_id = $(this).attr("style");
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData($("form#uploadForm-"+edit_id)[0]),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,   
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("success!");
        },
        error: function() 
        {
        }
   });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

upload.php

```
<?php
if(is_array($_FILES)) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
$sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "upload/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
echo $targetPath;
}
}
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using 'id' use 'class'. Using 'id' the binding is only working for the first element. The even is only being binded to the first ID that's hitting that. Instead use

```
<input type='submit' style = '$row[asset_ID]' class='uploadPicture btn btn-primary' value = 'Upload'>
```

Now modify the script like this

```
$('.uploadPicture').click( function(e) { // <-- starting with '.' means for all objects of this class
var edit_id = $(this).attr("style");
$.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData($("form#uploadForm-"+edit_id)[0]),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,   
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert("success!");
    },
    error: function() 
    {
    }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

That should do the trick.
And if you want to take my advice then I'd say using an ID in 'style' attribute is really bad idea. I'd say use it like this

```
<input type='submit' id = '$row[asset_ID]' class='uploadPicture btn btn-primary' value = 'Upload'>
```

And identify it in the script like

```
$('.uploadPicture').click( function(e) {
var edit_id = $(this).attr("id"); // <------ pick from id
$.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData($("form#uploadForm-"+edit_id)[0]),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,   
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert("success!");
    },
    error: function() 
    {
    }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: This post made me very happy. Thank you so much sir! I learned new tricks and this code revision finalized my whole project! Thank you sir Unrealist!!!!

Comment: Hmm I have a question. It's now a good thing that the AJAX works perfectly no matter what the row is but this error "Unidentified index: userImage" keeps on showing up when I try to upload on the following rows. I think I have a problem with this "new FormData($("form#uploadForm-"+edit_id)[0])".

Comment: Since I can't test the php here, I can't tell for sure but I think the issue is with the forms not having the 'enctype' attribute set. Set that attribute as
<form .............. enctype='multipart/form-data'>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$('#uploadPicture').click( function(e) { ...`
use `$('#uploadPicture').on('click', function(e) {...`

Comment: I tried that but the problem still occurs. I can upload a file on the first record. But when i try to upload on the following rows (2nd, 3rd row, etc.), the whole ajax thing won't work. I appreciate your help btw.

Comment: It's like the following rows doesn't have a <form> because I can only upload on the first record. Do you know how to uniquely define a <form> in this scenario?

Comment: You can't use same id for multiple pictures.